# meta内の日本語の違和感

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

現状では、質問のソートに「アクティブ」「今話題」「今週」「今月」の4種類がありますが、

[image: meta SO 上部]

この2つ目「今話題」というのは日本語として、あまりに口語的かつ意味が不明瞭です。
「最近の話題」などの日本語に変更する方がよいのではないかと思われます。

Comment: entoの案を次回のビルドで適用。

Answer (score 3):

他の案も出します:

> 人気

「注目」は [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae) タグとかぶるので、混在させない方がいいかなと思います。

Answer (score -1):

> ホット

はどうでしょう。

Comment: What's HOTみたいなかんじですねー。
伝わるのかな。

Comment: はてなブックマークで「ホッテントリ」という言い方が浸透している(?)ようなので、伝わるかなと期待しましたが、どうなんですかね

Comment: 確かにホッテントリは浸透しているのですが、運用時にホットは抽象的すぎて「ホットって何だっけ？」ってなることがよくあるので僕はさけてます。

Comment: @eccyan なるほどおもしろいです。抽象的すぎるという意味では「話題」や「人気」も同じですか?

Comment: @ento 確かにそうですね。今週/今月に紐付いて「今」話題となってると思うのですが、どの期間かわかるラベリングの方がこの場合いいと思います。ですので、人気も今人気であれば大丈夫なのでしょうが・・・。
でも、英語版だとhotになってますね